# Column Range Queries in CQL3

Tags: cassandra, cql

If I have a table defined like:

```
CREATE TABLE metrics (
  schedule_id int,
  time timestamp,
  value double,
  PRIMARY KEY (schedule_id, time)
);
```

It's straightforward enough to select the latest timestamp & value for a single key:

```
SELECT time, value FROM metrics WHERE schedule_id = 1 ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;
```

...but how can I efficiently select the latest timestamp and value for every row?

Something like a `GROUP BY schedule_id` in regular SQL or a column range query (which is no longer supported IN CQL 3.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a naïve solution, since I am unaware of how your use case will tolerate variances in the data due to Cassandra's eventually-consistent and last-write-wins semantics.  But as often the case in Cassandra, the way to support different views (or ways of querying) your data is to denormalize and store it in multiple ways that make that convenient.

```
CREATE TABLE latest_metrics (
    metric_name text,
    schedule_id int,
    latest_time timestamp,
    latest_value double,
    PRIMARY KEY (metric_name, schedule_id)
);
```

When you insert data into `metrics`, at the same time also write into `latest_metrics` (this assumes your data is always input in monotonically increasing time, like from a real-time feed).

```
INSERT INTO metrics (schedule_id, time, value) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
INSERT INTO latest_metrics (metric_name, schedule_id, latest_time, latest_value)
    VALUES ('WellKnownIdentifier', ?, ?, ?);
```

In this case, "latest" is really in terms of when the record was written and not the actual *timestamp* field value.  If you are ingesting data that comes with interleaved times, you will likely have to take care of this on your application side.  You could also potentially use new new Compare-and-Set (CAS) functionality in Cassandra 2.x, but the Paxos process required to do that will severely impact your write performance:

```
INSERT INTO latest_metrics (...) VALUES (...) IF latest_time <= ?;
```

If all of these assumptions work for your data, you can query the "latest" value for all schedules easily enough:

```
SELECT schedule_id, latest_time, latest_value FROM latest_metrics WHERE metric_name = 'WellKnownIdentifier';
```